# Verification of Improved constants in Brun-Titchmarsh theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

For $q,a$ relatively prime, let $\pi(x,q,a)$ denote the number of primes less than $x$ which are congruent to $a$ modulo $q$. The [Brun-Titchmarsh theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brun%E2%80%93Titchmarsh_theorem) states that $$\pi(x,q,a)\leq \frac{(2+o(1))x}{\phi(q)\log(x/q)}$$ for all $q<x$.

Set $\theta=\frac{\log q}{\log x}$. The Brun-Titchmarsh theorem may be rewritten as $$\pi(x,q,a)\leq(C(\theta)+o(1)) \frac{x}{\phi(q)\log x},$$ where $C(\theta)=\frac{2}{1-\theta}$. Depending on the range of $\theta$, there have been improved bounds on $C(\theta).$ [Fouvry, Theorem 3](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01388980) proved the following bounds:
[image: fouvry]

However, the paper is written in a language unfamiliar to me. [Baker-Harman](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-4086-0_4) corrected [Fouvry](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01388980)'s bounds till $\theta=5/7$ in their paper. I want to know if larger bounds on $C(\theta)$ were correctly proved in [Fouvry](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01388980). Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's behind a paywall, so I can't help with the language issue. You can e-mail me at sylvainjul'at'gmail'dot'com if needed.

Comment: @Sylvain JULIEN you can view the  fouvry paper on this website.(https://eudml.org/doc/143202)

Comment: Thank you but it's not really readable on my device, it seems the encoding of mathematical expressions doesn't match the original one.